# extracting numbers with units from string

Tags: r, gsub, strsplit

I have a series of strings as below:

```
x <- " 20 to 80% of the sward should be between 3 and 10cm tall, 
with 20 to 80% of the sward between 10 and 30cm tall"
```

I want to extract the numeric values and keep the units, I have tried the following:

```
x <- lapply(x, function(x){gsub("[^\\d |cm\\b |mm\\b |% ]", "", x, perl = T)})
```

Which gives:

```
" 20  80%       3  10cm   20  80%     10  30cm "
```

What I need is:

```
"20 80%" "3 10cm" "20 80%" "10 30cm"
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: will there always be an `and` or a `to` between the ranges?

Comment: try `library(stringr);do.call(rbind,lapply(str_extract_all(x, '\\d+(\\s+|cm\\b|%)'), function(x) {m1 <- matrix(x, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE); paste(m1[,1], m1[,2])}))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `str_extract_all` from `library(stringr)` to extract the elements that matches the pattern (modified based on comments from @PierreLafortune)

```
library(stringr)
lst <-  str_extract_all(x, '\\d+\\S*')
```

If the length of the `list` elements are the same, we can `rbind` them to create a `matrix`.

```
m1 <- do.call(rbind, lst)
```

`paste` the alternating columns together

```
v1 <- paste(m1[,c(TRUE, FALSE)], m1[,c(FALSE, TRUE)])
```

and convert it back to `matrix`.

```
dim(v1) <- c(nrow(m1), ncol(m1)/2)
v1
#     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     
#[1,] "20 80%" "3 10cm" "20 80%" "10 30cm"
```

Comment: @user3857437  You can have different patterns to extract.  My code was based on the example posted by the OP.

Comment: There was not always an and or to between the number range, I accomplished what I needed with the following: 


x <- str_extract_all(x, '\\d+ ?(cm|%|mm)? ?(to|and|[:punct:])? ?(\\d+)? ?(cm|%|mm)?')


x <- lapply(x, function(x){gsub("and|to", "-", x)}) 


x <-rbind.fill(lapply(sward,function(y{as.data.frame(t(y),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)}))


Thanks for the quick answers

Answer (score 0):

Not particularly elegant but...

```
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
" 20  80%       3  10cm   20  80%     10  30cm " %>%
str_split(" ") %>%
unlist %>% 
as.data.frame %>% 
    plyr::rename(replace = c("." = "string")) %$%
    gsub(string, replacement = "", pattern = " ") %>%
    as.data.frame %>% 
    plyr::rename(replace = c("." = "string")) %>%
    filter(string != "") -> etc_etc
```